# GITLAB - Permalink for download latest Release form my repository

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

Do you know if GitLab have any permalink for download LATEST Release (zip format) from my repositories?

Gitlab's documentations and issues is confused about this simple functionality..

Answer (score 4):

[GitLab 14.9](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/03/22/gitlab-14-9-released/#permanent-link-to-the-latest-version-of-a-release) (March 2022) could help, and proposes:

> ### Permanent link to the latest version of a release
>
> Prior to this update, to refer to the latest release of a project, users needed to know the exact version number.
>
> We have now added a link to the latest [release](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/releases/) for a project.
> This makes it much easier and more efficient to navigate to the latest release.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/releases/#permanent-link-to-latest-release) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/16821).

You now have:

> Latest release page is accessible through a permanent URL.
> GitLab will redirect to the latest release page URL when it is visited.
>
> The format of the URL is:
>
> ```
> https://host/namespace/project/-/releases/permalink/latest
> ```
>
> We also support, suffix path carry forward on the redirect to the latest release.
> Example if release v14.8.0-ee is the latest release and has a readable link `https://host/namespace/project/-/releases/v14.8.0-ee#release`, then it can be addressed as:
>
> ```
>  https://host/namespace/project/-/releases/permalink/latest#release.
> ```

And:

> ### [Permanent links to latest release assets](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/releases/#permanent-links-to-latest-release-assets):
>
> The filepath from permanent links to release assets can be used in combination with permanent link to the latest release.
> It is useful when we want to link a permanant URL to download an asset from the latest release.
>
> The format of the URL is:
>
> `https://host/namespace/project/-/releases/permalink/latest/downloads/:filepath`
>
> If you have an asset with filepath for the v11.9.0-rc2 latest release in the gitlab-org namespace and gitlab-runner project on gitlab.com, for example:
>
> ```json
> {
>  "name": "linux amd64",
>  "filepath": "/binaries/gitlab-runner-linux-amd64",
>  "url": "https://gitlab-runner-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/v11.9.0-rc2/binaries/gitlab-runner-linux-amd64",
>  "link_type": "other"
> }
> ```
>
> This asset has a direct link of:
>
> ```
> https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/releases/permalink/latest/downloads/binaries/gitlab-runner-linux-amd64
> ```

Answer (score 2):

There is not currently an API endpoint to get the latest release. There is a feature proposal at https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/26254.