# GITLAB - Permalink for download latest AppImage Release from a repository

Tags: download, gitlab, permalinks, appimage

Somehow a follow up questions to:
[GITLAB - Permalink for download latest Release form my repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57417584/gitlab-permalink-for-download-latest-release-form-my-repository)
*(I wanted to comment below, but this is only allowed after 50 posts or so)*

**Is there a way to put together a permalink (to the latest release of an App) to an AppImage File  to download it via curl or wget?**

My example is LibreWolf:
LibreWolf Website Link to Appimages: https://librewolf.net/installation/linux/
It already brings you to this: https://gitlab.com/librewolf-community/browser/appimage/-/releases

So the permalink for the latest release (while I'm writing it is v123.0-1) is:
https://gitlab.com/librewolf-community/browser/appimage/-/releases/permalink/latest
(this guides you to the files of this release only: https://gitlab.com/librewolf-community/browser/appimage/-/releases/v123.0-1)

**So now I would like to have a permalink to the AppImage File of this latest release?!**:
https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/24386000/packages/generic/librewolf/123.0-1/LibreWolf.x86_64.AppImage
(file seems to have a generic name: "LibreWolf.x86_64.AppImage", while the link-text on the release page is: "LibreWolf-v123.0-1.x86_64.AppImage")

Thx in advance for any help. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Not really a permalink, but API version and Project ID should be relatively constant so I will use this for now:
https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/24386000/packages/generic/librewolf/latest/LibreWolf.x86_64.AppImage

-->
wget -O LibreWolf.x86_64.AppImage  https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/24386000/packages/generic/librewolf/latest/LibreWolf.x86_64.AppImage

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).